# Java: XML to Object (or Array)

Tags: java, xml, object

How could I convert a XML Document to a Java Object (or Array)?
I readed the XML like this:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

Document doc = dBuilder.parse(new File("file.xml"));
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
```

Now I want that XML as Object (or Array) but how should I do this?
Are there any methods or tutorials or classes out there to do that?

Comment: What kind of object do you need and what kind of XML file do you have? You need to clarify more, otherwise the answer is "You did it!", since `Document` is an `Object` and has been built from an XML file.

Comment: what do u mean by "I want that XML as Object", so what is doc?, can u describe exactly what u want?

Comment: Sorry for that mistake, I should better say (just) array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need [JAXB unmarshaling](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing3.html).

Answer (score 9):

Use [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/).

**Object to XML**

```
Person joe = new Person("Joe", "Walnes");
joe.setPhone(new PhoneNumber(123, "1234-456"));
joe.setFax(new PhoneNumber(123, "9999-999"));
String xml = xstream.toXML(joe);
```

The resulting XML looks like this:

```
<person>
  <firstname>Joe</firstname>
  <lastname>Walnes</lastname>
  <phone>
    <code>123</code>
    <number>1234-456</number>
  </phone>
  <fax>
    <code>123</code>
    <number>9999-999</number>
  </fax>
</person>
```

**XML to Object**

```
Person newJoe = (Person)xstream.fromXML(xml);
```

**Also see**

- [Reference](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html)
- [Simple](http://simple.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Check out:  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html and http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-simple.html

Comment: life.java:  I've seen the XStream tutorial.  If you want to see something cool, check out this MOXy example demonstrating XPath based mapping (I'm the tech lead):  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html

Comment: @Blaise Doughan Ah, Misunderstood your comment, Thanks nice stuff.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) for XML (de)serialization. It's **way** simpler than using Java's built-in XML APIs.

Comment: Check out:  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html

Comment: No problem.  Also JAXB is a standard so there are multiple implementations:  Metro (the RI included in Java SE 6), EclipseLink MOXy (I'm the tech lead), and JaxMe

Answer (score 1):

I would look at JAX/B, which gives a way to "bind" between Java objects and XML representations.

I've got a tiny write-up of doing it with Rational Eclipse-based tooling [here](http://djna.wordpress.com/2010/08/02/flazr-and-redirection-with-a-smil/), but there appear to be (never used them myself) straight Eclipse plugins too, for example [this](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/09/05/new-version-jaxb-21-eclipse-plugin).

Indeed writing JAX/B by hand is possible, gets a bit dull for complex XML, but annotations are quite easy.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Simple XML](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) and have found it quite easy and powerful.  I am not as familiar with XStream, but Simple lets you control your XML schema using annotations which gives you a lot of freedom.  The guy who writes it is always responsive on his mailing list.

Comment: Checkout:  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-simple.html