# how import the values in tables from text files

Tags: java, jdbc

i am making a program where I would read data from txt files and store them in tables in mysql. At the beginning of my program the table would be created with all the fields that it would contain (ID, name, text,price,date,litres)
The code is shown above:

```
private static String getCreateTable1(Connection con, String tablename) {

try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    String createtable = "CREATE TABLE " + tablename
            + " ( ID INT, name VARCHAR(255), text VARCHAR(255), price INT , date DATE, litres DECIMAL (20,8) )";
    System.out.println("Create a new table in the database");
    stmt.executeUpdate(createtable);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(((SQLException) e).getSQLState());
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return null;
}
```

The issue that i have to solve is that the data in text files are as shown in the image: [image]

The ID is in the third line, the NAME is in the fifth line, then there is a line which has data that would not be stored somewhere, and after one line there are four columns of data. The first is the "text" after the "price", next the "date" and at the end the "litres"

How could i make it to read for example the third line and take only the value of the ID and store it in the ID field? Could anyone help me?

Comment: Storing dates as varchars?? Uh, I don't know of _any_ SQL engine not having a native date type

Comment: It;s just a sample of table.You are right bu the purpose of the question is not this.

Answer (score 0):

In the first place your data would have been better off in XML format, and then using an XML parser you could have read the data nicely and converted them into your objects.

I'm guessing you haven't even created an object to load your data into, so let me help you with that:

```
public class MyDataObject {

    int id;
    String name;
    DataTable table;

    private class DataTable {
        String col1;
        int col2;
        Date date;
        int col3;
        int col4;
        DataTable(...) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Now after reading your text file (guessing you don't know that either so here's another utility method for your code base:)

```
static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding) 
  throws IOException 
{
  byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
  return encoding.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(encoded)).toString();
}
// Usage:
// String content = readFile("test.txt", Charset.defaultCharset());
```

You will need a utility method in your code base to parse the XML string into a document:

```
public static Document loadXMLFromString(String xml) throws Exception
{
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
    return builder.parse(is);
}
```

The last thing left is to map your XML data to your data object (MyDataObject).

For that, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4441071/1031312).

You might want to compile a List/ArrayList of your objects and then you can loop through them and access the data easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly import data from CSV file in your SQL command. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Also you can read it from CSV in java and then store into the database, see http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/